# StringBuilder replace method run like insert method

Tags: java, replace, stringbuilder

I try to replace some string in `StringBuilder` using the `replace` method, but unfortunately it running like the `insert` method.

Here is some code:

```
public class StringBuilderReplace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append("Line 1\n");
        builder.append("Line 2\n");
        builder.append("Line 3\n");

        builder.replace(builder.indexOf("Line 2"), builder.indexOf("Line 2"), "Temporary Line\n");

        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }
}
```

The result for this code:

```
Line 1
Temporary Line
Line 2
Line 3
```

**What I want is:**

```
Line 1
Temporary Line
Line 3
```

How to do this to get the result I want?

**Update based on AljoshaBre answer**

It works if I change the code like this one:

```
builder.replace(builder.indexOf("Line 2"), builder.indexOf("Line 3"), "Temporary Line\n");
```

But new problem occur, what if the next string (for this example `Line 3`) I don't know the content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you're getting index of "Line 2" as starting index, which is the beginning of that line, and you do the same for the last index.

I think you should do the following:

```
public class StringBuilderReplace {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            builder.append("Line 1\n");
            builder.append("Line 2\n");
            builder.append("Line 3\n");

            String lineToReplace = "Line 1\n";
            int startIndex = builder.indexOf(lineToReplace);
            int lastIndex = startIndex + lineToReplace.length();

            builder.replace(startIndex, lastIndex, "Temporary Line\n");
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
        }
}
```

Comment: It works, but how if I don't know if the next string is `Line 3`?

Comment: builder.replace(builder.indexOf("Line 2"), builder.indexOf("Line 2") + "Line 2\n".length(), "Temporary Line\n");

Comment: Get the length of the string you want to replace, and add that value to the value returned by `builder.indexOf("Line 2")` (in this example). That will be your last index.

Answer (score 2):

```
final String toReplace = "Line 2\n";
final int start = builder.indexOf(toReplace);
builder.replace(start, start+toReplace.length(), "Temporary Line\n");
```